# Карта сайта. Как изменить цвет ссылок?

Tags: css

Как заменить цвет текста: "написать письмо" с фиолетового на другой? Хотя бы на белый?

```css
ul.svertical {
  width: 200px;
  /* width of menu */
  overflow: auto;
  background: black;
  /* background of menu */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 7px;
  /* top padding */
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.svertical li {
  text-align: right;
  /* right align menu links */
}

ul.svertical li a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgb(127, 201, 68);
  /* initial background color of links */
  font: bold 16px Germand;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  /* spacing between links */
  color: black;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset -7px 0 5px rgba(114, 114, 114, 0.8);
  /* inner right shadow added to each link */
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset -7px 0 5px rgba(114, 114, 114, 0.8);
  box-shadow: inset -7px 0 5px rgba(114, 114, 114, 0.8);
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  /* CSS3 transition of hover properties */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

ul.svertical li a:hover {
  padding-right: 30px;
  /* add right padding to expand link horizontally to the left */
  color: black;
  background: rgb(153, 249, 75);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset -3px 0 2px rgba(114, 114, 114, 0.8);
  /* contract inner right shadow */
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset -3px 0 5px rgba(114, 114, 114, 0.8);
  box-shadow: inset -3px 0 5px rgba(114, 114, 114, 0.8);
}

ul.svertical li a:before {
  /* CSS generated content: slanted right edge */
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 70px 0 0 20px;
  /* Play around with 1st and 4th value to change slant degree */
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent black;
  /* change black to match the background color of the menu UL */
}


/* 2 прикреплённый файл ССS  - 1.css */

.li uu {
  color: #FFFFE0;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.stu {
  color: #FFFFE0;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.styll {
  color: #FFF68F;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  margin-left: 370px;
}

.styy {
  color: #fafad2;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Segoe UI Semibold;
}

.sty {
  color: #FFF68F;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.st {
  color: #ffff99;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.s {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.styles {
  color: #00F5FF;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center
}

.styletest {
  color: #C1CDCD;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center
}

.style {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 62px
}

.stylll {
  color: #FFF68F;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.ss {
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.stuu {
  color: #FFF68F;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.sl {
  color: ;
  #FFF68F;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

:after,
:before,
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block-middle {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.block-middle:after,
.block-middle:before {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.block-middle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  left: -15%;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff), -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff), -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff), -ms-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff), -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);
  background-size: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.block-middle:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  right: -15%;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff), -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff), -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff), -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff);
  z-index: 10;
}

.block-middle .img-block {
  width: 33.33%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.block-middle .img-block img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <title>formula of the soul</title>
  <!-- **Favicon** -->
  <link rel="icon" href="fons/x.ico" />


  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      line-height: 1.5em;
    }
    
    b {
      font-size: 110%;
    }
    
    em {
      color: red;
    }
    
    #topsection {
      background: url(fons/a.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
      height: 220px;
      /*Height of top section*/
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-family: Arial;
      color: #FAEBD7;
    }
    
    #topsection h1 {
      margin: 0;
      padding-top: 15px;
    }
    
    #contentwrapper {
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
      background: url(fons/big.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
    }
    
    #contentcolumn {
      margin: 0 200px 0 230px;
      /*Margins for content column. Should be "0 RightColumnWidth 0 LeftColumnWidth*/
      color: #FFF68F;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-family: Verdana;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #leftcolumn {
      float: left;
      width: 230px;
      /*Width of left column*/
      color: #FFF68F;
      margin-left: -100%;
    }
    
    #rightcolumn {
      float: left;
      width: 200px;
      /*Width of right column*/
      margin-left: -200px;
      /*Set left marginto -(RightColumnWidth)*/
      background: #FDE95E;
    }
    
    #footer {
      clear: left;
      width: 100%;
      background: black;
      color: #FFF;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 4px 0;
    }
    
    #footer a {
      color: #FFFF80;
    }
    
    .innertube {
      margin: 10px;
      /*Margins for inner DIV inside each column (to provide padding)*/
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    /* ####### responsive layout CSS ####### */
    
    @media (max-width: 840px) {
      /* 1st level responsive layout break point- drop right column down*/
      #leftcolumn {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      #rightcolumn {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
        clear: both;
      }
      #contentcolumn {
        margin-right: 0;
        /*Set margin to LeftColumnWidth*/
      }
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
      /* 2nd level responsive layout break point- drop left column down */
      #leftcolumn {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        clear: both;
        margin-left: 0;
      }
      #contentcolumn {
        margin-left: 0;
      }
    }
    
    a.button7 {
      font-weight: 700;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: .8em 1em calc(.8em + 3px);
      border-radius: 3px;
      background: rgb(64, 199, 129);
      box-shadow: 0 -3px rgb(53, 167, 110) inset;
      transition: 0.2s;
    }
    
    a.button7:hover {
      background: rgb(53, 167, 110);
    }
    
    a.button7:active {
      background: rgb(33, 147, 90);
      box-shadow: 0 3px rgb(33, 147, 90) inset;
    }
    
    a.button9 {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      color: #FFE7BA;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) 1px 1px, rgba(100, 100, 100, .3) 3px 7px 3px;
      user-select: none;
      padding: 1em 2em;
      outline: none;
      border-radius: 3px / 100%;
      background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .0) 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .8), rgba(255, 255, 255, .0) 70%), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 90%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(125, 125, 125, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(125, 125, 125, .5)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(125, 125, 125, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(125, 125, 125, .5)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(223, 190, 170, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(223, 190, 170, .5)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(223, 190, 170, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(223, 190, 170, .5));
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 200% 100%, auto, 100% 2px, 100% 2px, 100% 1px, 100% 1px;
      background-position: 200% 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 0 4px, 0 calc(100% - 4px);
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 3px 10px 10px -10px;
    }
    
    a.button9:hover {
      transition: .5s linear;
      background-position: -200% 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 0 4px, 0 calc(100% - 4px);
    }
    
    a.button9:active {
      top: 1px;
    }
    
    body {
      /* webkit adjacent sibling bug fix */
      -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes bugfix {
      from {
        padding: 0;
      }
      to {
        padding: 0;
      }
    }
    
    div.nav {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
      perspective: 1000px;
    }
    
    div.nav input {
      display: none;
    }
    
    div.nav label.mainlabel,
    div.nav div.menuflip {
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
      transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
      /* transition speed etc */
    }
    
    div.nav label.mainlabel {
      /* menu anchor text style */
      width: 200px;
      /* width of anchor text */
      font: bold 20px Tahoma;
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      display: block;
      padding-left: 34px;
      /* add left padding to make room for icon */
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    div.nav label.mainlabel:before {
      /* menu anchor icon */
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      border: 7px solid darkgreen;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px gray, 0 0 5px gray;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px gray, 0 0 5px gray;
      border-radius: 30px;
    }
    
    div.nav div.menuflip {
      /* DIV that flips over to reveal main menu */
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0;
      top: 0;
      padding: 4px;
      background: white;
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
      width: 200px;
      border: 1px solid gray;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px #B5B5B5;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px #B5B5B5;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background: #eee;
    }
    
    div.nav div.menuflip h4 {
      margin: 0;
      margin-bottom: 4px;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 4px 0 0 6px;
    }
    
    div.nav div.menuflip ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    div.nav div.menuflip ul li {
      border-bottom: 1px inset gray;
    }
    
    div.nav div.menuflip ul li:last-of-type {
      border-bottom: none;
    }
    
    div.nav div.menuflip ul li:hover {
      border-bottom-color: transparent;
    }
    
    div.nav div.menuflip ul li a {
      display: block;
      color: blue;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 6px;
      border-radius: 10px 0 10px;
      -webkit-transition: none;
      transition: none;
    }
    
    div.nav div.menuflip ul li a:hover {
      background: #515151;
      color: white;
    }
    
    div.nav div.menuflip label.close {
      /* close button */
      position: absolute;
      right: 5px;
      top: 8px;
      padding-top: 1px;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 14px;
      color: white;
      z-index: 1000;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 50px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background: black;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    div.nav input:checked~label.mainlabel {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    
    div.nav input:checked~div.menuflip {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
      transform: rotateY(0);
    }
  </style>


  <script src="https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?139" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="g3.css">
  <script src="https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?143" type="text/javascript"></script>



</head>
<!-- google_ad_section_start -->

<body>
  <div id="maincontainer">


    <div id="topsection">
      <div class="innertube">
        <h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h1>
      </div>



    </div>
  </div>




  <div id="contentwrapper">
    <div id="contentcolumn">
      <p>

        <br>
        <div class="innertube"> <em></em>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            filltext(45)
          </script>
        </div>

        <div class="stuu">


          <p>
            <p><i>"Ф.Д."TEXT
  <br> Вы можете:</i>


        </div>

        <span class="styy"><a href=".html"><span style="styy">написать письмо</span></a>
        </span>

        <span class="stuu"> с меткой темы
                </span>
        <br>

        <span class="s"><a href=""><i></i></a></span>



        <p>
          <br>

          <div class="stuu"><i>Cтоимость~</i>
          </div>
          <br>

          <br>
          <div class="styles"><a href=".html" class="button7">Заказать сейчас</a>
          </div>
          <br>

          <p>





            <div class="share42init" data-description="
  "></div>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://astrovok.esy.es/share42/share42.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://userapi.com/js/api/openapi.js?33"></script>





            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://zornet.ru/ZORNET-RU/jquery.min_raketa.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://zornet.ru/ZORNET-RU/MrScrollUp_raketa.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://zornet.ru/ZORNET-RU/MrScrollUp_raketa.css" />
            <div id="MrScrollUp" style="display:none;">
              <div class="MrScrollUp1"></div>
              <div class="MrScrollUp2"></div>
            </div>





    </div>
  </div>




  <div id="leftcolumn">
    <div class="innertube"><b><i><ins></ins></i></b>
      <ul class="svertical">
        <li><a href=".html"> TEXT</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        filltext(20)
      </script>
      <!-- VK Widget -->
      <div id="vk_groups"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        VK.Widgets.Group("vk_groups", {
          mode: 1,
          width: "220"
        }, 9894839);
      </script>

      <p>



    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="rightcolumn">
    <div class="innertube"><b></b>

      <br style="clear: left" />
      <div class="nav">

        <input type="checkbox" id="togglebox" />
        <label for="togglebox" class="mainlabel" id="mainlabel_ie">Site Menu </label>

        <div class="menuflip" id="menuflip_ie">
          <h4><i>Консультации</i></h4>
          <ul>
            <li> <a href="index.html" class="button9">Главная страница </a>
            </li>

          </ul>
          <label for="togglebox" class="close">x</label>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      filltext(15)
    </script>
  </div>


  <div id="footer"><a href="http://www.">A </div>
    <div class="styletest"><i> При копировании материалов данного сайта прямая ссылка на сайт обязательна © 2017</i> </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте стиль тегу `<a>`

```
a {
  color: #000;
}
```

Также можно сделать изменение цвета при наведении на ссылку:

```
a:hover {
  color: #0000ff;
}
```

Эти действия изменять цвет ссылок везде.

В Вашем случае смените значение свойства `color` в классе `.styy`.

Comment: признателен за ответ) только цвет  a { color: #000; } - это чёрный, я заменил на white и добавил  тег стиля a в верх страницы html, а свойства color в класс styy.  теперь все работает